# Проверить, есть ли введенное число в массиве.

Tags: c

Проверить, есть ли введенное число в массиве. 
Показывает, что 1 есть, а больше ничего. В чем дело?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check(int massive[], int chsl) {
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if (chsl==massive[i])
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
int massive[5] = {5,4,7,2,3};
int chsl,l;
printf ("Введите число: ");
scanf ("%i",&chsl);
l=check(massive,chsl);
if (l==0)
    printf ("Число есть в массиве!");
else
    printf ("Такого числа в массиве нет!");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас, судя по всему, перепутаны условия:

```
if (l==0)
    printf ("Число есть в массиве!");
```

Очевидно это сообщение должно выводиться если l ненулевое.

Comment: Ой, точно, спасибо.

Comment: @user193688 осваивайте отладчик, пришло время.

Comment: @user193688, нажмите на галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае функция `check` написана некорректно, так как она не учитывает размер массива, а вместо этого использует в цикле "магическое число 5.

Правильно было бы написать функцию следующим образом

```
int check( const int massive[], size_t n, int chsl ) 
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && chsl != massive[i] ) i++;

    return i != n;
}
```

В `main`, которая в C должна иметь объявление

```
int main( void )
```

функцию можно вызывать следующим образом

```
if ( check( massive, sizeof( massive ) / sizeof( *massive ), chsl ) )
    printf ("Число есть в массиве!");
else
    printf ("Такого числа в массиве нет!");
```

Или

```
l = check( massive, sizeof( massive ) / sizeof( *massive ), chsl );

if ( l )
    printf ("Число есть в массиве!");
else
    printf ("Такого числа в массиве нет!");
```

В C лучше никогда не проверять логические значения на точное равенство 1. Лучше делать проверку на неравенство 0 или на равенство 0.